# tinyMCE insert image and upload

Tags: tinymce

```
tinyMCE has a "insert image button" wich it asks URL.
I want to add browse button so that user can upload image from pc.
I have writed server side PHP files that will grab image and store in server.
the php file will return URL of stored image on server and tiny MCE must grab URL of stored image and insert below code to the source of editing text.
```

```
<img src='http://mysite.com/url_that_php_file_returns.jpg'/>
```

is it Possible?

Comment: have a lokk at the tinymce MCImageManager plugin: http://www.moxiecode.com/products_imagemanager.php

Answer (score -3):

i wrote a plugin myself. It was not that hard.

Comment: Would be grateful if you can share it?